# kerio load balance

Tags: load-balancing

I use kerio winroute 6.5 , for week ago, i got a second adsl link (2 mbps), i tried to configue the load balancing in kerio  , but always , kerio directs the traffic to one route without the other , i enabled NAT for firewall and change the rate between 2 links but always kerio takes the system route to one link , is there a solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a hardware firewall device, or software running on your server?
Can you provide any more info about your network infrastructure and configuration?